# SQL Injection on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-injection

stackoverflow has helped me immensely in my coding career by always having the right answers to my questions. This question however might be a bit specific and hopefully it doesn't get harsh responses as it is my first posting to the site.

I'm interested in creating a SQL Server 2012 stored procedure that allows users to search various columns. I believe I've created a stored proc that does what I expect it to, but I'm concerned about SQL Injection attempts. Have I covered all my available bases with SQL Injection in mind? If not, please educate me on the ways to circumvent my sample stored proc. Please Note: the one noted has been modified to protect the company's data structure.

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSearch]
(      
     @searchTerm varchar(50) = NULL
)  
AS

set @searchTerm = LTRIM(RTRIM(@searchTerm));

select  a.ID
       ,a.Col1
       ,a.Col2
       ,a.Col3
       ,a.Col4
       ,a.Col5
       ,b.Col1
from table1 a
left join table2 b on a.ID = b.ID
where (a.Col1 like '%' + @searchTerm + '%'
    or a.Col2 like '%' + @searchTerm + '%'
    or a.Col3 like '%' + @searchTerm + '%'
    or a.Col4 like '%' + @searchTerm + '%'
    or b.Col1 like '%' + @searchTerm + '%'
    or b.Col2 like '%' + @searchTerm + '%'
    or b.Col3 like '%' + @searchTerm + '%'
    or b.Col4 like '%' + @searchTerm + '%'
    or b.Col5 like '%' + @searchTerm + '%'
    or b.Col6 like '%' + @searchTerm + '%')
GO
```

My main concern is the posibility of passing hostile SQL commands into the 50-character varchar parameter and having it execute in any of the various where like clauses.

Comment: You have covered the SQL injection attack by using parameter. The hostile commands would be seen as plain "search text" as if you are searching for a string of the hostile command.

Comment: This isn't a concern at this level.  It is already parameterized, so it would behave as if it was a lookup on the value of the parameter.

Comment: BTW, you might still be introducing SQL injection attack hole at the point where you are getting this parameter and sending to SQL server.

Comment: @CetinBasoz How would that be possible?

Comment: @Siyual, somewhere using a front end language (say C#) you would want to get a "searchTerm" from the user and call this procedure. If you are not using parameters in your front end , you are still introducing an SQL injection attack point, no?

Comment: @CetinBasoz Ah, I see what you mean.  Yes, if you're invoking this stored procedure via string concatenation (e.g.: `string sql = "Exec spSearch '" + txtSearch.Text + "'";`) then, you are still wide open for SQL injection.  But if you call it properly with parameters, you're fine :)

Comment: I won't be calling it inline line that, so based on what I'm reading it should be fairly secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how you call the SP from code. The Stored Procedure is self is not safe from sql injection. When you are using parameterized functions you are probably fine. When you are sending sql queries as string, than you still have a sql injection problem. The main problemen is the string concatenation in your code. String concatenations are never safe if you have parameters from an untrusted source. [Do Stored Procedures Protect Against SQL Injection?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2011/02/16/do-stored-procedures-protect-against-sql-injection/)

The basic lesson is to write Stored Procedures without any string concatenations.

Comment: Thanks, Peter! I have no plans to use string concatenation in calling this stored proc, so I'm leaning toward this being a fairly secure stored proc.

Comment: You are doing string concatenation in the sp: '%' + @searchTerm + '%'. So the sp it self is not secure. It seems your method of calling the sp makes the usage secure.